# How to pass data from two UITableViewCells using AlertBox and CoreData?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I am working on an app which has TableViewCells in three Scenes. I would like to populate by using an AlertBox to take the "item tapped" and pass that data to a TableViewCell in another Scene..

Here is the first Scene I have the alertBox in

```
class SupplementScene: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, 
UITableViewDelegate
{
@IBOutlet weak var lblSupplement: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sbSupplement: UISearchBar!

@IBOutlet weak var tvSupplement: UITableView!

let stackScene = StackScene()

var suppArray:[Supplement] = [Supplement]()
var stackArray:[Stack] = [Stack]()

let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell1"

var count:Int = 0

   // create the managed object context
// it is used for CoreData. Must be created in the ViewController
let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate
    as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    applyDesign()
    tvSupplement.dataSource = self
    tvSupplement.delegate = self
    suppArray = CoreDataHandler.getAllSupplementObjects(managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
}

// functions from the protocols
// number of rows in table view
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return suppArray.count
}

// create a cell for each table view row
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
    // had to change cell to cell1 since identified was used before
    let cell:SupplementTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1") as! SupplementTableViewCell!

    // set the text from the array into the cells labels
    cell.lblName.text = suppArray[indexPath.row].name
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    cell.lblName.textColor = UIColor.white

    return cell
}

// method to run when table view cell is tapped
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    //        print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row).")

    // get the tableViewCell
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! SupplementTableViewCell
    // print the text property in the label in the tableViewCell
    print("TableView tapped = \(cell.lblName.text!)")

    updateStack(name: cell.lblName.text!)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// update function
func updateStack(name:String)
{
    // get the objectby name
    _ = CoreDataHandler.getSupplementByName(managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, name: name)!

    // create an Alert with a textFields for all ContactBusiness fields
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Udpate \(name)",
        message: "",
        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    // create a default action for the Alert
    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(
        title: "Ok",
        style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,
        handler: {(alertAction: UIAlertAction!) in
            // get the input from the alert controller
            // put the user updated fields back in the contactBusiness object

            // save the managedObject
            CoreDataHandler.addStackObject(managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)

            // get all Contacts from CoreData
            self.stackArray = CoreDataHandler.getAllStackObjects(managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)

            // reload the data into the TableView
            self.tvSupplement.reloadData()
            self.stackScene.tvStack.reloadData()


    })

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(
        title: "Cancel",
        style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel,
        handler:nil)

    // add the action to the Alert
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    // display the Alert
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

and now the class in which I want to retrieve the data from.

```
class StackScene: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource
{
@IBOutlet weak var lblStack: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sbStack: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet weak var tvStack: UITableView!

let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell3"

var stackArray:[Stack] = [Stack]()
   // var suppArray:[Supplement] = [Supplement]()
var count : Int = 0

// create the managed object context
// it is used for CoreData. Must be created in the ViewController
let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate
    as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    tvStack.delegate = self
    tvStack.dataSource = self

    stackArray = CoreDataHandler.getAllStackObjects(managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)


    // doing this to apply the design changes to the app
    applyDesign()

}

// functions from the protocols
// number of rows in table view
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return stackArray.count
}

// create a cell for each table view row
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
    // had to change cell to cell1 since identified was used before
    let cell:StackTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell3") as! StackTableViewCell!

    // set the text from the array into the cells labels
    cell.lblName.text = stackArray[indexPath.row].name
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    cell.lblName.textColor = UIColor.white

    return cell
}

@IBAction func longPressDelete(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
{`enter code here`
    // get the location of the long press in the table
    // location returns a CGPoint
    let p = sender.location(in: tvStack)

    // get indexPath at location of the long press
    let indexPath = tvStack.indexPathForRow(at: p)

    // if nil, selected the table, not a row
    // if not nil, check for long touch began.
    // we are not interested in the long touch ended
    if indexPath == nil
    {
        print("Long press on table view, not row.")
    }
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began)
    {
        // get the tableViewCell
        let cell = tvStack.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! StackTableViewCell
        print("TableView LongPress = \(cell.lblName.text!), Pos: \(indexPath!.row)")

        // call the deleteContact function
        deleteContact(name: cell.lblName.text!, position: indexPath!.row)

        // do something for long press here
    }
    else if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended)
    {
        print("Long press ended")
    }
}

// function to display alert and confirm deletion
func deleteContact(name:String, position:Int)
{
    // create the AlertController
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Delete",
                                            message: name + ": Confirm Delete",
                                            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    // create a default action button
    let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete",
                                     style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,
                                     handler: {(alertAction: UIAlertAction!) in
                                        // remove from array
                                        self.stackArray.remove(at: position)
                                        // reload the tableView
                                        self.tvStack.reloadData()
                                        // remove from CoreData
                                        CoreDataHandler.deleteStackByName(managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext, name: name)
    })

    // Alerts can only have one cancel action
    // It is bolded and always comes last
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
                                     style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel,
                                     handler: nil)

    // Add the actions to the Alert
    alertController.addAction(deleteAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    // present or display the Alert
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

I know I am not using a segue to perform this type of transaction. But I have searched these threads and google for any info and am struggling on what is the best solution to this. The alertBox pops and has the tapped item in the textField, but I cannot get the data from that alertBox textField to populate into the TableViewCell of the "stack" class.

Let me know if there is any other info I can provide. I am still learning Swift.

Comment: It’s really hard to figure out what you want here. Your UIAlertController doesn’t have a textField. Do you want to pass the `name` across?

Comment: Hi Warren, yes, I want to pass the `name` that is in the UITableViewCell of the `Supplement` TableView to the Cell of the `Stack` TableView. Does that help?